# Inversify : contextual injection with class name

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I am trying to inject loggers into different classes using [inversify](http://inversify.io). I want to pass the target class name to the logger to categorize it.

The problem is I can't access the target name from where i'm creating the binding:

```
container.bind<log4js.Logger>(Types.Logger).toDynamicValue(context => {
    let className = context....?; // Finds class name
    return log4js.getLogger(className);
});
```

Is there any way of doing this other than setting it once the logger is created in the object receiving the logger?

Thank you!

Antoine

Comment: Not familiar with your library but `object.constructor.name` is a way to get the class name of an object

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the said 'object'. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: 
This [new feature](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/576) makes it possible to access the class name from the context. The name will be minified though. This can be solved by comparing against the class.

```
container.bind<Warrior>(TYPE.Warrior)to(Ninja).inActivation((context) => {
    const currentClass = context.currentRequest.bindings[0].implementationType;
    if (currentClass) {
        if (currentClass === Ninja) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

**Original post**: 
<del>Thanks for asking this question. What you are looking for it is not possible at the moment but I have created an issue in GitHub to ensure that we do something about it. You can learn more about it at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/issues/576</del>

Comment: Thanks a lot, Remo!